# Analyze query in database tuning advisor disabled

Tags: sql-server, ssms

This is disabled in SQL Server Management Studio. It's an Azure database - is this not supported or am I missing something to use this option?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of azure index are constantly observed. If performance degrades it will recommend to create index. But in case of duplication or unusability of indexes for upto 93 days, it is recommended to delete the index.

Comment: Ok, great. How do you receive those recommendation? And is your answer that the reason its disabled is because Mangement Studio does not work with Azure SQL Server?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-advisor